# Bash reorganize and write text to excel table

Tags: excel, bash

I have a raw text file that is space delimited that I want to generate an excel file with. A very small sample of the format is below:

```
Name1
Name1 Field1 Value1a
Name1 Field2 Value2a
Name1 Field3 Value3a
Name2
Name2 Field1 Value2a
Name2 Field2 Value2a
Name2 Field3 Value3a
Name2 Field4 Value4a
Name2 Field5 Value5a
Name2 Field6 Value6a
Name2 Field7 Value7a
.
.
.
Name N
NameN Field1 Value1c
NameN Field2 Value2b
NameN Field3 Value3a
NameN Field8 Value8a
NameN Field6 Value6d
NameN Field7 Value7a
```

What I'd like to do is delete the "blank" lines and reorganize it in the following format using a script.

```
      Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4  Field5  Field6  Field7  Field8
Name1 Value1a Value2a Value3a
Name2 Value2a Value2a Value3a Value4a Value5a Value6a Value7a
.
.
.
NameN Value1c Value2b Value3a                 Value6d Value7a Value8a
```

I've referenced a lot of information on getting this far but can't figure out this last part.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Consider generating CSV, which is very simply to script and excel can still read and translate into an .xsls.

Comment: would you mind using perl? Since you would need some arrays and hashes, and bash is a bit too low to be comfortable with this. I would read line by line into a hash of second column ("Field6")  to Value of third column (Value6a). If a new Name is coming in Column 1, just print the current fields. You need a first full scan to find out which fields are possible, but after that you could iterate over all the fields in headline and then in all the `print_row` calls. And yes, CSV is what you want to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a CSV file, can Excel can open natively.

Assumption: your input data does not contains spaces or tabs, except as field separators

```
gawk '
    NF < 3 {next}
    !($1 in names) {names[$1]}
    !($2 in fields) {fields[$2]}
    {data[$1,$2] = $3}
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
        for (f in fields) printf ",%s", f
        print ""
        for (n in names) {
            printf "%s", n
            for (f in fields) {
                printf ",%s", (data[n,f] == "") ? "\"\"" : data[n,f]
            }
            print ""
        }
    }
' file > file.csv
cat file.csv
```

```
,Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5,Field6,Field7,Field8
Name1,Value1a,Value2a,Value3a,"","","","",""
Name2,Value2a,Value2a,Value3a,Value4a,Value5a,Value6a,Value7a,""
NameN,Value1c,Value2b,Value3a,"","",Value6d,Value7a,Value8a
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn, that worked perfectly for my application.